# Should convert String to Int in java @ 1.5 or use other method?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in which I want to terminate program by pressing any key(whether character or numbers), so I did a conversion from string to int using **Integer.parseInt(variable)** method and compare choices if it is not desired choice it should terminate the program but it show an error **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: for input string: "d"**.

program code is as follows:-

```
public class mainClass {
    public static void main( String[] ar ) {
        double res = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
        Tdata td1 = new Tdata(); // another class object

        System.out.println( "****Temperature Conversion****" );
        System.out.println( "------------------------------" );
        System.out.println( "Press 1-> C2F" );
        System.out.println( "Press 2-> F2C" );
        System.out.println( "<- Press aNY kEY TO Exit ->" );

        String choice = in.nextLine();

        // =======================================================
        int ch = Integer.parseInt( choice );
        System.out.println( "String has converted: " + ch ); 
        // verifying if converted into int
        if( ch == 1 || ch == 2 ) {
            if( ch == 1 ) {
                td1.getVal( 37.4 );
                res = td1.C2F();
                System.out.println( "Resulted Temperature: " + res );
            }
            else if( ch == 2 ) {
                td1.getVal( 104.2 );
                res = td1.F2C();
                System.out.println( "Resulted Temperature: " + res );
            }
            else {
                System.out.println( "mind your input plz" );
            }
        }
        else {

            System.out.println( "<- You select to exit ->" );
            System.exit( 0 );
        }
        // =======================================================
    }// end of main
}// end of public class
```

Now I think that I should convert undesired input to its previous state ie. String state.. is it right way or should Try another predefined method available in *api*.

-Thanks!
 Niks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare characters instead of converting them to integers:

```
if (choise.isEmpty()) {
    //user pressed Enter
} else if (choise.charAt (0) == '1') {
    //user pressed 1
} else if (choise.charAt (0) == '2') {
    //user pressed 2
} else {
    //user pressed another key(s). exit here
}
```

Comment: `if (choise.isEmpty() {` - Looks like you forgot to end the parentheses of your conditional. Also, it's "choice" -- spelling and OP's variable name.

Comment: Thanks! added closing bracket. about choice vs choise: I'm not a native speaker and my dictionary recognizes both words and gives the same translation. What is the correct word?

Comment: Your dictionary must be lerping the word, choice is the correct one, choise doesn't exist.

Comment: Well new code gives an error, i just change erroneous code with new one.
it says:-  <br>
mainClass.java:43: cannot find symbol<br>
symbol : method isEmpty()<br>
location: class java.lang.String
if(choice.isEmpty())<br>
         ^
(i m not much experienced but since last few mistakes i hv learnt that this 1 occurred when method/subclass is not defined in the parent class.)
however i have commented out the infected code (if-block) than program got execute.

I have also checked in specification that there is no var.isEmpty() defined besides other one are defined.</pre>

Comment: i m really i could not make my reply as readable as yours; and so many thanks to the person who have edited description of my prob above, i guess it is **tangens** 
:) thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `Scanner`, you might as well use `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` instead of doing `Integer.parseInt()`.

Try this snippet: enter numbers, non-numbers, etc. Enter 0 when you're done.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter code: ");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("int, please!");
            sc.next();
        }
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        if (num == 0) break;
        System.out.println("Got " + num);
    } while (true);
    System.out.println("DONE!");
```